# Couldn't open non-google URL's in google appscript

Tags: google-apps-script

So i'm trying to open a url in a **Gmail Addon** using google **appscript's** Cardservice.newOpenLink().setUrl().
The strange thing is it can open google's url's(ex:[www.google.com](http://www.google.com), google's authorizartion url) but it couldn't open non google's url(Ex:[www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com)). Has google appscript restricted non google url's? Does anyone have any idea on this?

```
`function buildAddOn(e) {
 
 
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
  var section = CardService.newCardSection();

  // Create a navigation button that navigates to 
  var action = CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('openNewPopup');
  var button = CardService.newTextButton().setText('Click to open').setOnClickAction(action);
  section.addWidget(button);

  card.addSection(section);

  return card.build();
}

function openNewPopup(e) {


  var link = CardService.newOpenLink()
    .setUrl("https://www.facebook.com")
    .setOpenAs(CardService.OpenAs.OVERLAY);

  var actionResponse = CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
    .setOpenLink(link)
    .build();

  return actionResponse;
}`
```

in the above code if i replace google.com with any other url i get the following error in the gmail add-on

```
The value returned from Apps Script has a type that cannot be used by the add-ons platform. Also make sure to call build on any builder before returning it. Value:Object with values: '
    - {
  "openLink": {
    "url": "https://www.facebook.com",
    "openAs": "OVERLAY"
  }
}'.
```

Answer (score 0):

From [setUrl() docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/open-link?hl=en):

> Sets the URL to be opened. The URL must match a prefix [whitelisted in the manifest](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/workspace-manifests?hl=en#manifest_structure_for_gmail_add-ons).

From [manifest docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest?hl=en#Manifest.FIELDS.urlFetchWhitelist):

> urlFetchWhitelist[]: A list of HTTPS URL prefixes. If present, any URL endpoint fetched must match one of the prefixes in this list. This can help to protect user data. This field is optional for test deployments, but is required for deployments. Learn more about [allow listing URLs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/allowlist-url?hl=en).

Last link is guide about adding items to whitelist.

Comment: Hi, do you konw how can we change font-family in gmail add-on google appscript?